# New Nest Doorbell (wired) SDM Support

Tags: nest-device-access

I received and installed the new [Nest Doorbell (wired)](https://store.google.com/us/product/nest_doorbell) over the weekend and wanted to play around with it today via the SDM API but I discovered it was not listed in my Device List and while "Nest Doorbell (wired)" is listed in the [supported devices](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/supported-devices), it seems to still refer to the 1st generation Nest Doorbell (wired).

Is there typically a lag between launch and SDM API support for new Nest devices or have I missed a setting/configuration somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: +1
I paid to replace a battery-powered doorbell that dies in the cold with the gen. 2 wired version and this is what I get for doing it... it's not yet supported. Wow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**"Is there typically a lag between launch and SDM API support for new Nest devices...?"**

Yes.

Nest Doorbell (battery)

- release date - 08-24-21    - source - 9to5google - [link](https://9to5google.com/2021/08/05/google-nest-doorbell/)
- SDM support - 09-21-21   - source - release notes - [link](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/release-notes)

Nest Cam (indoor, wired)

- release date - 10-05-21   - source - 9to5google - [link](https://9to5google.com/2021/10/05/nest-cam-floodlight-wired-release/)
- SDM support - 11-18-21   - source - release notes - [link](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/release-notes)

**"...or have I missed a setting/configuration somewhere?"**

I doubt it. Lots of other users are reporting the same issue (see this [thread](https://www.googlenestcommunity.com/t5/Cameras-and-Doorbells/Doorbell-2nd-gen-wired-no-SDM-API/m-p/259327) in the official help forum).

Answer (score 2):

It's working now, SDM updated with doorbell Gen 2 recently.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out the hard way to realize 2nd gen wired Doorbell isn't supported in SDM. Half of my household members are hearing impaired and dependent on flashing lights triggered by doorbell press.

Comment: Just a heads up, I tried chatting with a rep on the google store page because this doesn't seem like an actively monitored support channel and they directed me to "Leave feedback" on the [Google Nest Community](https://www.googlenestcommunity.com/t5/Cameras-and-Doorbells/Nest-Doorbell-wired-2nd-Gen-SDM-API-Support/m-p/259620#M47747).

Seems like that community is more actively monitored, so hopefully that will provide a faster resolution of this issue.